# Missing terms with gathered

Tags: equations

For some unknown reason when I'm compiling this code I'm missing the first part of the first row:

```
\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{gathered}
[Q_\alpha,Q'_\beta] = [P_\alpha,P'_\beta] = 0, \\
[P_\alpha,Q'_\beta] = [P'_\alpha,Q_\beta] = \dfrac{h}{2\pi i}\delta_{\alpha \beta}\delta(\pmb{r}-\pmb{r}')
\end{gathered}
\end{equation}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The bracket is the culprit: `\relax[Q_\alpha,Q'_\beta]`

Comment: the missing bits should have been accompanied by an error message in the log, although that is perhaps not as understandable as one might wish.

Answer (score 1):

`gathered` is sufficiently smart that

```
tokens \\
[tokens]
```

doesn't mistake `[` as the indicator of an optional argument (this would happen in `tabular` or `array`).

However, it's not smart enough to do the same for the first line, so your `[` is taken as the opening of an optional argument. Since it's neither `t` nor `b`, it gets ignored.

Solution:

```
\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{gathered}\relax
[Q_\alpha,Q'_\beta] = [P_\alpha,P'_\beta] = 0, \\
[P_\alpha,Q'_\beta] = [P'_\alpha,Q_\beta] = \dfrac{h}{2\pi i}\delta_{\alpha \beta}\delta(\pmb{r}-\pmb{r}')
\end{gathered}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: do you think I should fix that? (seems to have come up a couple of times this week)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I don't think that fixing it would break existing document.

Comment: by "fix it", do you mean in `amsmath`?  (this would have no effect on `eqnarray`,  which, as far as i'm aware *does* mistake the `[` as an option following `\\ `.  but, of course, `eqnarray` should not be used.)  i agree with @egreg that it is not likely to break existing documents, unless there *is* a genuine option on the environment that is preceded by a space.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Ha, ha! That would indeed be a stopper.